# Is leaving the <style> section out because I already imported all my styles in the App.vue file a bad practice?

Tags: vue.js, sass

I found the way that components are laid out very comfortable considering I use SASS with the [7-1 architecture](https://sass-guidelin.es/#architecture) for my styling. I thought I would be writing SASS directly in the component file but when I searched on Google how to use it with Vue I found out that I can just import `main.scss` in `App.vue` and never have to declare a `<style></style>` section in any other component.

My question is whether or not this is a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fine, its an architecture choice, some prefer a more centralized styling while other use the style tags with or without the scope feature.
Depends also on your needs if styles repeat themselves in many components it makes sense to centralize, whereas a highly specialized style you might want to consider putting in the tag although not a must.